# Replacing the last characters of a string value with the id of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I have got the columns [id, account_id] in my table. And the values are

```
+------+----------------+
| id   |    account_id  |
+------+----------------+
| 1    |  01-01-02-0007 |
| 2    |  04-05-06-0001 |
| 3    |  03-07-09-0001 |
| 4    |  03-04-04-0001 |
| 5    |  03-04-08-0101 |
| ...                   |
| 201  |  03-04-08-0111 |
+------+----------------+
```

What I want is replace the last part of the each of `account_id` after `-` i.e. `0007`, `0001` and `0001` etc in this case with respective `id` (but still padded with the `0`s to the left to make it 4 characters). To be more specific, below is what I want to achieve:

```
+------+----------------+
| id   |    account_id  |
+------+----------------+
| 1    |  01-01-02-0001 |
| 2    |  04-05-06-0002 |
| 3    |  03-07-09-0003 |
| 4    |  03-04-04-0004 |
| 5    |  03-04-08-0005 |
| ....                  |            
| 201  |  03-04-08-0201 |
+------+----------------+
```

I thought to use `REPLACE` but unfortunately, that can't be applied to my case, since it is not just the part ( that remains same for each value) that I want to change. I have been searching, but I am unable to achieve this. I think, I would have to use some regular expression and `LPAD` in some way to achieve this, but not sure how.

Can anyone please show me some light?

Comment: You can create an update statement with the use of [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad). However, that would mean you have the same data repeated on 2 locations in your table. I don't know your design, but I'd investigate whether using a `SELECT CONCAT(account_prefix, '-', lpad(id, 4,'0')) as account_id` throughout your application isn't more apt / avoid confusion.

Comment: Does the account number vary in length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the very simple case with fixed account number lengths you're showing, this will do;

```
UPDATE accounts
SET account_id=CONCAT(LEFT(account_id,9), LPAD(id, 4, '0'))
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5e05/1).

Answer (score 0):

If account_id format would not be changing, you can use
`substring_index`, `lpad`, and `concat` to apply changes as you wanted.

```
update my_table 
set account_id = 
      concat( substring_index( account_id, '-', 3 ), '-', lpad( id, 4, '0' ) )
```